# External testing on testflight rejected because demo account needed

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

I submitted my app for review to start external beta testing and I got the response:

> Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
>
> ...but we are not able to continue because we need a demo account to
>   fully assess your app features.

The app requires verification by phone number (same as when you install whatsapp), and sends a message to the phone number, but there is no "demo account". Do I need to create an account which they can access, with a phone number, and a pre-set verification code in this case? The app is based on the contacts on the phone, so the "experience" won't work as it would for a user this way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes create a basic demo account that they can login to - Apple is strict about this.

Once you are finished you can either update the information and email them back or handle it through the Resolution Center. I updated the app information in iTunes connect with the demo login information and replied to the rejection email stating the demo account information, shortly after that the app was approved for TestFlight.

They basically just need to be able to see as much as possible within your app, so even if what shows is minimal that is fine.

Comment: but this way, if the account is already logged in, then they won't be able to see the onboarding process, because I would have already onboarded them. And since the users who are added to the game aren't users they would have in the phonebook, they would not be able to see how this whole thing works! thanks

Comment: As said, just give them a demo login, that's the only way they'll approve it. If it needs a phone number explain that to them, or create a temporary phone number they can use perhaps.